# How to extract "path expression" from an interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, union-types, recursive-type

What I want to achieve is this:

```
type Post = {
  id: number
  title: string
  author: {
    name: string
  }
  comments: {
    text: string
  }[]
}

type ExtractPathExpressions<T> = ???

type Paths = ExtractPathExpressions<Post>
// expects above got a union --> 'id' | 'title' | 'author' | 'author.name' | 'comments' | `comments[${number}]` | `comments[${number}].text`
```

I know this is unusual... but, does anyone know what would the `ExtractPathExpressions` look like?

Comment: it may be possible with the brand new [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html). Something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGCGwAsCMUC8UDksCuiD2AThgNwCwAUKJDPAgExqYB2sAthBlAD6bACWwADYcylcNABiePIwAGAEgDecREgC+AOiUr6a2aKiGoAemNQAelABEOfAQ0t2V7tdsJCG-kIhWKQA) is how you would construct the paths. But the hard part is the recursion  - for whatever reason `keyof T` (where `T` is a generic) can't be templatized when using mapped types

Comment: @Chase - that's not true, `keyof T` can be used just fine, but one needs to be aware that an unconstrained `keyof T` gives a `string | number | symbol`. The `symbol` type cannot be used in a template literal type (just as a `Symbol` can't be directly used). If one takes care to exclude the `symbol` type from `keyof T`, there are no issues. This is still a hard type to define, though

Comment: @OlegValter I should've made it clear in my original comment - I meant `T` where it is constrained to extend a `Record<string, any>` - it still seems to throw an error- https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJwDwBUoQB7AgOwCYDOUAShAMYD2CeSBwCAljgOYA0UcOIAfN1ALxQA3gFgAUFElQA2gGkoTKAGsIICgDMoKALoAuKAAMAJENkBfA+KlQA9DesPHkgHroECKlAAWEBBHFmANzi4nZaPlDqFAA20RQA7kzMUPFUSkRwRJiQZNh4UAC0UDgUUMy4vgxkRACuBBB44qCQUAAiNQC2HSACwlZSDHj6OJ0ARr7BElLADMDREPp0jCyTQSFizdAAYhSlgqJTknIKOMqqGm2d3XqGJuaWYmbrQA

Comment: @Chase - thank you for clarifying! The reason is the same, though - `keyof T` in an unresolved `T` is `string | number | symbol`, which leads to an error (granted, it is not super useful because the innermost msg says `string` is not assignable to `number`, but the real culprit is the `symbol`). This is solved like this: `type Bar<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: `${Exclude<K, symbol>}` //all ok now
};`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is certainly not an unusual task, but it is a complex recursive one that requires separate handling for different cases where a property:

1. is of a primitive type
2. is a nested object
3. is a nested array

Recursion is required for cases 2 and 3 as both can contain other nested objects and arrays.

You want to create a *union* of all possible permutations of paths, so at each step, we have to return a union of the key itself and the template literal concatenating the key and a result of the recursive `ExtractPathExpressions` on the property unless it is of primitive type.

The type itself should obviously be a mapped type (in the sample below I opted for the newer key remapping feature) with keys that can be used in template literal types (a union of `string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined`), which means the `symbol` type must be excluded.

This is how the desired type could look like:

```ts
type ExtractPathExpressions<T, Sep extends string = "."> = Exclude<
  keyof {
    [P in Exclude<keyof T, symbol> as T[P] extends any[] | readonly any[]
      ?
          | P
          | `${P}[${number}]`
          | `${P}[${number}]${Sep}${Exclude<
              ExtractPathExpressions<T[P][number]>,
              keyof number | keyof string
            >}`
      : T[P] extends { [x: string]: any }
      ? `${P}${Sep}${ExtractPathExpressions<T[P]>}` | P
      : P]: string;
  },
  symbol
>;
```

Testing it out:

```ts
type Post = {
  id: number
  title: string
  author: {
    name: string
  }
  comments: {
    text: string,
    replies: {
        author: {
            name: string
        }
    }[],
    responses: readonly { a:boolean }[],
    ids: string[],
    refs: number[],
    accepts: readonly bigint[]
  }[]
}

type Paths = ExtractPathExpressions<Post>;
//"id" | "title" | "author" | "comments" | "author.name" | `comments[${number}]` | `comments[${number}].text` | `comments[${number}].replies` | `comments[${number}].responses` | `comments[${number}].ids` | `comments[${number}].refs` | `comments[${number}].accepts` | `comments[${number}].replies[${number}]` | `comments[${number}].replies[${number}].author` | `comments[${number}].replies[${number}].author.name` | ... 4 more ... | `comments[${number}].accepts[${number}]`
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZ2FAvFA3gWAFBSgSwBMAuKAOwFcBbAIwgCcc9h9gAbCUpe-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-wANzzH0IIllNg4QFD7ArcDQO1id5oGu2htNp0ti7wJCAnAAej31MgdfeQjKADdoHw4MghFAKGQW1AALTP4EAciI75D75Y7Ag36su+IjiJIgFQMBviSH8ZAKABP46HoLyGOBEqIfohg6ugHrKqqIZoboGEIFhOEqn8zwWHGOCQmCQhOFAOiZMgzxIL2DYINOLHICgPG-OhyHEQAjAkfypOkmTuD8UAHgA8gA0is7jcbxPz8QYxEAAwiQ0cRaVJskKTO2CrPO7EAOqsGIRoglsq72o6CDOq227ADcPx7kC07URAtH0YxSBQFxRpseICAWeIRqcUp1k8WgPwgX4e6wYo+l7vJQA)

Comment: @yaquawa - I had to do the reverse recently (parsing a recursive type from a set of arbitrary paths) - well *that* was quite a time sink :)

Comment: @yaquawa - with a bit of an improvement, it should now also handle nested arrays of primitive types much better (had to resort to exclusion of `keyof string | keyof number` since other approaches result in overflow of the recursion depth limit and thus error)

Comment: Hi Oleg, could you give me another variant version of this which allow specify the target type for extracting? For instance `ExtractPathExpressions<Post,number|boolean>` will only gives 'id' | 'comments.responses[${number}].a'

Comment: @yaquawa - well, you can use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to filter out the unwanted types upfront. It is easy to do - I can draft it up later, but you should include that in the question as well or the update will be out-of-place. For now revisited the type to make separator configurable (came in handy for one of my projects)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. But I found a small problem in the proposed solution `ExtractPathExpressions`.

If you want to get the key of an array, you will get all the keys of its methods.

```js
type ArrayPath = ExtractPathExpressions<[number, number]>;
// number | "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | "push" | "concat" | "join" | "reverse" | "shift" | "slice" | "sort" | "splice" | "unshift" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | ... 19 more ... | "1"
```

I adapted the solution to work with arrays and extract subtypes it to make it easier to read the code. You can see my solution [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=67&ssc=1&pln=47&pc=1#code/PTAEFMA8BcCcEMDG1QHsB2AbAnqaALVAZ3FAGtxsi994VaA3UgI3HHVABNwAzAS3ThOoZrgCuRALAAoaNgAOpAMIToqALYBpSgB4AKgD5QAXlABRSIkxjuOitlQ9QegDSgi2dc1SZQAH3JKR1AxdDJ0VAB3dABtAF1-QIcndDEvcFhE%202CiOAEAcwMAbhkZEFB8cExFWBk5RVAAQWZchGQAeWYAK3BkE1AAJV7UWE4dVoLE1PTYN3h0bGLS6XLK6oy8VFBEWHA6UnhYBFx7OoVSADFMOkaj%20GxtbB1GiBh2Tmp57HjE3fhODA4UBfeJuTSvaDvagTdD5KZpVizUAABQhUPceVhRmMMlAiU0uMSAAMACQAb00AF8YuTpojKXEiYSAqSKdTaQiMgzycjKeSVLkNI8dFc6M8YnSMnEDAZKUSStIymA1jVNts-pC0N1eihTrJzqBRdBOj1kML2mj0B8mi04EhjdrkGDLdaYXCApKkaioJCrdDMYUTMzQKyqTy%20WSBWotLojTp2jK5cHNAqygAqQk7PaQz6gHjXFD1Ug8WAaUACSGwHhIUgjPDnQk8OtQeDqeSYcAALmWeIrGR4iFIAFUSJkyYS8ehW12MbACgq8b30E3O6Bx9JF4vKnx8vhoKvPQvN6BIuAd3uD5zYEe8ZTCXfFRvthhcnmCyOMqu4x-YNi1xPQAAcindRwEA1cADooJcADAIEJsIO3XdoHA0AoIgmCnzxODl1QCDT3PFDIOg%208ZDTYAZCgeQRkLA041cFEXX9OdYX6QCIMAv91zxGJwQEUAoyFXRDGBag9F4hIfXREEEgCP4ASwXAZIAgB%20Q0C1uY5hXEzQ4jBNxkQMADVx0yS3j9G1WntE0dVU9S6Bss1hIk-SUSMrDQFXXTV1CcIonQBVKVTFYwHycBoGoAhSHkOh8DzOsvlAeRSxqORyw4KL60USjIGo2BaIaZFYvaHh9D-Cw7WQOwgiceiDDcN0lkfcozAADUaABZZEABkzBkPsqxrFFiBQbjy04S8ZiPaA%20GgDtVzdI94DEAgRlXMbJ2nBaAyPILMw0UD0Ai9aAMhGBtpY-Ib1AXZ2z4cAiBOjy8WW1bYCe49FxAmdFoA29rupOJrt2IhqPQEhHpuvYFKBMlgVXbwfD2DhAeuvgPgugp4mB3hIc9bGAKQQd5GOqH-kBXBmB3CsCafVGZAfGREBfFAYoIVcioIEqdGREa-0A5n1EOiKYgABjiCCQbBiGxYl%20BAKKUBykiEYyGofJUFQTggA).

```js
type ArrayPath = PathOf<[number, number]>; // "0" | "1"
```

Full code:

```js
// gets the path for any property in the type
export type PathOf<T> = Extract<keyof Flat<T>, string>;

// creates a flat type from interface or type
export type Flat<T, P extends string = '.'> = {
  [K in CustomKey<T> as T[K] extends any[] | readonly any[]
    ? FlatArrayKey<T[K], K, P>
    : T[K] extends AbstractObject
    ? FlatObjectKey<T[K], K, P>
    : K]: unknown;
};


// extract only those keys that have been defined by us
type CustomKey<T> = Exclude<
    keyof T,
    symbol | keyof Array<unknown> | keyof number | keyof string
>;

// helper
type AbstractObject = Record<string | number, any>;

// helper to create array key
type FlatArrayKey<A extends any[] | readonly any[], K extends string | number, P extends string> =
  | K
  | `${K}[${number}]`
  | `${K}[${number}]${P}${CustomKey<Flat<A[number]>>}`;

// helper to create object key
type FlatObjectKey<O extends AbstractObject, K extends string | number, P extends string> =
    | K
    | `${K}${P}${CustomKey<Flat<O>>}`;
```

Example:

```js
type Post = {
  id: number
  title: string
  author: {
    name: string
  }
  comments: {
    text: string,
    replies: {
        author: {
            name: string
        }
    }[],
    responses: readonly { a:boolean }[],
    ids: string[],
    refs: number[],
    accepts: readonly bigint[]
  }[]
}

type Paths = PathOf<Post>;
//"id" | "title" | "author" | "comments" | "author.name" | `comments[${number}]` | `comments[${number}].text` | `comments[${number}].replies` | `comments[${number}].responses` | `comments[${number}].ids` | `comments[${number}].refs` | `comments[${number}].accepts` | `comments[${number}].replies[${number}]` | `comments[${number}].replies[${number}].author` | `comments[${number}].replies[${number}].author.name` | ... 4 more ... | `comments[${number}].accepts[${number}]
```

Hope I helped you!